# Frequency dependent capacitor for AC sweep analysis in LTspice

Tags: capacitor, simulation, ltspice, spice

I need to model a frequency dependent capacitor for AC sweep analysis in LTpsice. I see that it is possible for inductors with GLAPLACE component, but I don't find anything about capacitors. The value of that capacitor, in LTspice code, is:

Cap = (1/(pow((6.28*Frequency), 2)*InducFilter))

where InducFilter is a constant.

Here is the example of a frequency dependent inductor:

[Inductor example](http://acousticians.blogspot.com/2012/10/modeling-frequency-dependent-inductor.html)

Comment: To undersand the capacitance formula correctly: C(f)=Co*X(f) with X(f)=1/f², correct? So the capacitance C must be prop to 1/f² ?

Comment: Yes, it is derived from the equation: f = 1/(2*pi*sqrt(LC)).

Comment: Thank you for selecting the answer, but it may be best to wait a few days, maybe there will be other, better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example you saw in the link you provided makes use of the `Laplace` transfer function -- the so-called "GLAPLACE", no such thing (at least not in LTspice). Here is an example:

[image: ex]

To the right is what's in the link, to the left is what you'd want. As you can see, the inductor (`s*L`) is nothing more than the reverse of the capacitor (`1/(s*C)`). The slopes differ because the `Laplace` transfer functions use `sqrt(s)`.

Word of warning: The `Laplace` operator should not be used in `.TRAN` analysis, as it is *very* prone to errors and instabilities. In `.AC` it's perfectly fine, and extremely versatile, so you can adapt whichever `Laplace` transfer function you want. BTW, that's not LTspice code, you probably meant pseudo-code for your needs.

If you intend to do transient analysis, the only solutions you sould be using are the behavioural inductor (its value is of the form `Flux=f(x)`, see the manual for more) but which is sensitive to noise (use with care), or approximate the response with a Cauer or Foster topology (or whichever homegrown network suits you).

Comment: Thank you! I was in doubt because the G component is a voltage dependent current source so I thought that the Laplace Transform of that component must be expressed like I(s)/V(s) and not V(s)/I(s)

Comment: @FM79 To be fair, it's a transconductance, so you're right in that its transfer function is G=I/V, but if you are to simulate it as an impedance (be it R, L, or C), then, since it's trans*conductance*, it needs its transfer function reversed in order to make sense, Z=1/G=V/I.

Comment: Also, note that I am using a voltage source for all, which forces me to evaluate the impedance to `V/I`. Usually, and if the circuit allows, it's much easier to use a current source, with the same `AC 1`, which would mean that the impedance is simply `V/I=V/1=V`. Here, due to the G-source, I am forced to use a path for he current to ground, so I chose the voltage source. Using a current source would have meant two current sources in parallel, that's inviting the devil in any SPICE. So I chose the same for all, for consistency.